# rails 3 bartt-ssl_requirement page not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, https

I'm using the bartt-ssl_requirement gem to create an https connection on a shopping cart. The rest of the site doesn't need it.

In my application controller:

```
include SslRequirement
```

In my Orders controller:

```
ssl_required :new
```

Locally, I get an SSL Connection error:

```
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

In production I get page not found error:

```
The requested URL /orders/new was not found on this server.
```

So far I haven't been successful doing things like adding the :protocol attribute to the routes. Am I missing something?

Also, we have an htaccess file that redirects everything to www. Would this mess the https stuff up?

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirects to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapplication.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myapplication.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To be specific, I'm mostly concerned with the production error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently this was an Apache configuration issue with port 443. Wasn't set up for capistrano.